# Игнорирование ошибки таймаута python vk api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Если бот на питоне работает достаточно долго, то его выкидывает с ошибкой vk-api как

requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='im.vk.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=35)

Фулл ошибки:

```
File "Textv2.py", line 117, in
for event in longpoll.listen():
File "/home/h4x4d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vk_api/longpoll.py", line 621, in listen
for event in self.check():
File "/home/h4x4d/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vk_api/longpoll.py", line 557, in check
response = self.session.get(
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='im.vk.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=35)
```

Можно как-то ее игнорировать и продолжить выполнение, хотя бы через цикл? Мне не нравится что бот падает каждые 6 часов из-за этого. Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Пробовал постоянно отправлять ему сообщения, дабы "обновить таймаут", не помогает, он все равно упал

Comment: Алекс, привет. Тебе удалось решить проблему? У меня такая же история, отваливается бот, если долг оне происходят события. Не могу найти решение...

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать цикл while, в котором будет обработка этой ошибки

```
while True:
    try:
        your code...
    except ReadTimeOut:
        print("Переподключение")
        sleep(60)
```

Так же вы можете попробовать мою библиотеку https://github.com/lxstvayne/vk_maria. Под капотом есть обработка этой ошибки, а так же вы можете найти в ней некоторые удобства. Подробнее в документации.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        your code...
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Рекомендую это написать, выше описанный метод мне не помогал.
Команда pass позволяет пропустить ошибки и продолжить использование кода. Сам использую на pythonanywhere, но код все равно будет вырубаться, но намного реже.

Comment: Для любителей pass чище использовать [contextlib.suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress)

Answer (score 0):

Зная api vk дело скорее всего не в боте, а в их ограничениях-лимитах... если время падения стабильно равно 6 часам, то предлагаю автоматический перезапуск бота типа

```
       os.system(__file__)
       exit()
```